# Update after trigger on a table in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

My update trigger on a table looks like this.

```
CREATE trigger [HumanResources].[tr_update_department]
on [HumanResources].[Department]
for update
as
begin
insert into HumanResources.tbl_Department_audit
select * from deleted;
end
GO
```

I am basically looking for updated row information in audit table called  `tbl_Department_audit`.

I have tested the the trigger, whenever I am updating a *single* row in  `Department` table,
`two` rows with the before update and after update row information inserted in to the tbl_Department_audit.

What I expect is to audit only the one row either before update data or after update data, not both.

Comment: Can you post the content of your "before" trigger ?

Comment: Did you try using distict?  Select Distinct * From Deleted.

Comment: @maxiwheat : Triggered table have only one trigger that is the above one.

Comment: @jcwrequests  Single record may update in several times , we want to look all the updates on the perticular record. So distinct is not a good idea in this case.

Comment: if single record may update several times, wouldn't each time be different from the previous, why do you need auditing updates that didn't change anything?

Comment: @LuisLL  want to audit the updates on the triggered table.

Comment: that is clear, but if you can't use `distinct` as  @jcwrequests suggest, you are going to have duplicated records in your audit table, so it will means that some `no change` is registered.

Comment: BTW if you are using SQL 2008 or later you can use [Change Datea Capture](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @LuisLL we are using SQL 2005, yep there will be duplicated records.I want to capture all modifications, so duplicate may exist.             i looking to capture only one record (before updated record)for each update in the audit table.

Comment: please edit the question adding the `update` that you are doing. Maybe you have a join that results in 2 rows.

Comment: Are there any other triggers or column Defaults set?  That is likely where your apparent "After" row is coming from.

Comment: @RBarryYoung yeah that is the reason i got two rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the trigger script to as below

```
CREATE trigger [HumanResources].[tr_update_department]
on [HumanResources].[Department]
after update
as
begin
insert into HumanResources.tbl_Department_audit
select * from deleted;
end
GO
```

This should insert only one record after the update is done.

Comment: The `For/After` keywords are equivalent and do the same thing.